# How to avoid FileNotFound Error in django model ImageField when file does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model which has ImageField `img` and I have thousands of rows in the db while I also know some of the images in the db do not exist in the directory. But its an existing project and I cant do anything on that for now while the clients produce the missing images later.

But the issue is while retrieving a queryset without any reference or specific use of the image files, I get a `FileNotFound` error.

This happens both in Django admin once I paginate to a page that contains one of the records with missing file and also in a `ViewSet`'s `queryset` I try to create for frontend. And because I have not paginated the `ViewSet` queryset, I can't even test the endpoint without having the `FileNotFound` error.

How to catch this error or avoid it?

Comment: Well one solution would be to set a default on the imagefield..

Comment: @Jonas This is not at upload time. The records are already in db but trying to query the database just raised `FileNotFound` even without trying to use the files because indeed some files don't exist.

Comment: When in production, either set the default now for those missing or set the image field to `blank=True`

Comment: @Jonas they have file paths in them on db only that the files are not present in the directory. We like to keep the file paths in the db as it will help to get the images back from our archives later. So the error comes because there is a file path in the database field but the image is not in the directory

Comment: That's super bad design then. How can the db basically hold an url for an image that was never uploaded?