# Cant get rid of FileNotFoundError in Django ImageField

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models

I have a django model Product which has an image field

```
class Product(BaseProduct):
    img_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    img_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to=product_img_path, 
       height_field='img_height', width_field='img_width',
       null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Now because I loaded the products from an Excel file with records over 15,000 there are few that the image path in the file field does not actually exist in my directory.

This causes my code to raise a `FileNotFoundError` every time i try to `for product in Product.objects.all()` before I am even able to catch the error with a `try-except` block.

I'd like to have an iteration where I can check if the file exists and set the file field to null for records with non-existing files.

But this is impossible because the error is raised once I try to call an instance of the artwork or I create the iteration.

So the code below:

```
products = Product.objects.all()

for product in products:
    try:
        if product.file:
            pass
    except FileNotFoundError:
        product.file = None
        product.save()
```

Raised error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\project\\media\\products\\blahblah.jpeg'` and the stack trace shows error was raised from the iteration line `for product in products:`

I have tried following this thread without any luck: [How to avoid FileNotFound Error in django model ImageField when file does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71536127/how-to-avoid-filenotfound-error-in-django-model-imagefield-when-file-does-not-ex)

Development has progressed so I do not which to change the field type to char to perform the loop.

Any idea?

Comment: I haven’t managed to reproduce your issue. What Django version are you using ?

Comment: Maybe you have some migrations that have not been applied?  What is the result of `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Assuming the code breaks at that time in the loop does not really make sense. Django finds filepaths within the database and should therefore be satisfied. Only if you want to deal with the data or display the image the error will occur. It would be great if you could add the entire view that makes it break.

Comment: migrations is up to date. like I said its not a new app. I have just not figured out how to solve that problem. it now appears. @Zatigem to reproduce it you'll have to manually using sql insert record into ur db with an image that doesnt exist and try to query it with django model. I think its an error that is coming from the FileField or ImageField class while trying to prepare class attributes like name, width etc of the image file during loading the product instance. I dont think this is an isolated case.